# AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'could_extract_minus_sign' when trying to graph multiple equations

Tags: python, attributes

I am trying to graph multiple quadratic equations on one plot. My code is the following:

```
def f(x):
    return -1 * (x ** 2) + 5

def g(x):
    return 5 + (x ** 2) * cos(pi / (x ** 2))

def h(x):
    return (x ** 2) + 5



x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
functions = [f, g, h]
for func in functions:
    plt.plot(func(x), label=func.__name__)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

When I'm running the program I get `AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray'`. Do any of you know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I replaced the `cos` function with the version from `numpy`.
Then it works:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return -1 * (x ** 2) + 5

def g(x):
    return 5 + (x ** 2) * np.cos(np.pi / (x ** 2))  # CHANGED

def h(x):
    return (x ** 2) + 5


x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
functions = [f, g, h]
for func in functions:
    plt.plot(func(x), label=func.__name__)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some issues, first of all `cos` and `pi` are not defined, change them for `np.cos()` and `np.pi`

Aditionally, your cosine argument is `pi/x**2` and you defined `x` as `np.linspace(0, 1, 100)` that means you are doing some division by zero.

Correct version should be:

```
def f(x):
    return -1 * (x ** 2) + 5

def g(x):
    return 5 + (x ** 2) * np.cos(np.pi / (x ** 2))

def h(x):
    return (x ** 2) + 5



x = np.linspace(0.000001, 1, 100)
functions = [f, g, h]
for func in functions:
    plt.plot(func(x), label=func.__name__)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Where your linspace is starting in a value pretty near to 0 but, not 0.